# How to get the activity of a Google Drive file using Google Activity API

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am trying to integrate the Google Activity with my Application. I have integrated the Drive API and creating files in drive. I tried with the below code but i am getting some error.

```
var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/appsactivity/v1/activities";
    xhr.open('GET', url);//Document
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (typeof callback == "function") {
            callback(xhr);
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
        if (typeof callback == "function") {
            callback(null);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
```

Responce :

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidArgument",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

I have checked on Google and could not find any document to get the activity of a file.

Thanks

Comment: It should be related to the arguments you are passing with the request. Check the description for the errors in this page: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes. Also you can refer to this page for reference to do the get request for Google Activities API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/v1/reference/activities/list. Hope that helps!

Comment: Now i am passing the parameters as follows and authorization in header but getting Forbidden error 403. Get request url is https://www.googleapis.com/appsactivity/v1/activities?drive.fileId="+id+"&groupingStrategy=driveUi&source=drive.google.com

Comment: I found the problem. It was the problem with the activity scope. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/activity

Comment: Glad you are able to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Only work width WORKSPACE account, and the documentation is [doc API activity](https://github.com/googleworkspace/node-samples/blob/main/drive/activity-v2/index.js)

this code is not full, but i made it work.